# Simulate an enter action on mouseup event in IE11

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have this tag :

```
<a href="#top" id="atag"><img src="somefile.gif" /> </a>
```

We have a need to invert the `img` in the anchor tag on focus, so I have to use svg filter and javascript to achieve something like this on `focusin` event :

```
<a href="#top" class="svgImg" id="atag">
   <svg> 
   <image ... />
   </svg>
</a>
```

The `svg filter` works, but for some unknown reasons, after the `img` was replaced by the `svg`, I can't get the default behavior of the `anchor tag` any more by clicking it. I means when I click the inverted `anchor tag`, nothing happens. Even thought, when hovering over the `anchor tag` I still can see the `href` value of its displayed on the status bar.

I know this issue came from other javascripts in the project, but due to the size of it, I can't debug to the source of the prolem.

So I came to a temporary solution, which I will catch the `mouseup` event :

```
$('a').mouseup(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is('.svgImg') {
        this.click();
    }
});
```

This works as I expected, but then there was another problem which came from this `anchor tag` :

```
<a href="#top" class="svgImg" id="atag" onclick="updateProcess(this)">
```

After "clicking", it was called twice, and I don't know why, as I mentioned, the project is so huge that I can't find the problem.

Then I came to the idea of simulating an Enter key as the `anchor tags` are functioning normally if I press `enter` while they got focus.

My question is, can this be done?

FYI : You may want to question why do I have to go through all these troubles? Because the `anchor tags` I'm having in the project don't just simply contains a `href`, they also contain `onclick`, or being handle by some javascript like this `$('#someid').click(....)`  so .... !!!!

P/s : please ignore if there are any wrong javascript syntax, I'm typing all this out of memory, the actual code is working, no doubts.

Comment: possible to share the full js?

Comment: @user2181397 sorry I can't post the full js, it will violate our policy :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with jQuery? Try smth like this

```
$('#atag').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    //put what is needed
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this will only trigger the event handler, what I want is "simulate" an Enter without really pressing enter on the keyboard. The result would be the default behavior of the anchor tag after pressing enter